# Help understanding an inequality on Rudin's construction of the Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am having trouble understanding an inequality in Theorem 2.20 from "Real and Complex Analysis."

> Rudin states that if $f\in\operatorname{C}_c(\mathbb{R}^k)$ , $f$ is real, $W$ is an open k-cell which contains the support of $f$, and $\epsilon>0$
>   , such that
>
> (i) $g$ and $h$ are constant on each box belonging to $\Omega_N$
>
> (ii) $g\leq f\leq h$
>
> (iii) $h-g<\epsilon$
>
> If $n>N$, Property 2.19(c) shows that
>
> $$\Lambda_N g =
>  \Lambda_n g \leq \Lambda_n f \leq \Lambda_n h = \Lambda_N h$$

Here $\Lambda$ is defined as

> $$\Lambda_n f := \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} 2^{-nk} \sum\limits_{x \in P_n} f(x)$$

$\Omega_n$ is

> the collection of all $2^{-n}$ boxes with corners at $P_n$

$P_n$ is

> the set of all $x\in\mathbb{R^k}$ whose coordinates are integral multiples of $2^{-n}$

Property 2.19 (c) is

> For $\{\Omega_n\}$, if $Q\in \Omega_r$, then vol$(Q)=2^{-rk}$; and if $n>r$, the set $P_n$ has exactly $2^{(n-r)k}$ points in $Q$

What I don't understand is how Property 2.19(c) implies that $\Lambda_N g =
 \Lambda_n g$ and $\Lambda_N h =
 \Lambda_n h$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you calculate $\Lambda_ng $, you are adding over more boxes, i.e, you are subdividing the boxes from $\Omega_n $. But $g $ is constant over those additional boxes. Concretely,  a fixed  $x\in P_N $ corresponds to some box $Q\in\Omega_N $; then, as $g $ is constant in $Q $,
$$
2^{-nk}\sum_{y\in P_n\cap Q}g (y)=2^{-nk}g (x)\sum_{y\in P_n\cap Q}1
=2^{-nk}2^{(n-N)k}g (x)=2^{-Nk}g (x).
$$